# How to copy image data from file to HDD in Linux, with skipping some cylinders in HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, dd

I need to copy edited image to HDD correctly for my HDD portable media player.

Results of `fdisk -l`:

[image: Here is fdisk -l]

I need to skip 25 cylinders from the end of the data partition, and write to HDD edited RAW file.

I am copying that RAW file with command: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/mnt/disk/test.img skip=9704 ibs=8225280`

The file copying without any problem, but I need to orewrite this file, with skipping cylinders on `/dev/sdc`

The command `sudo dd if=/mnt/disk/test.img of=/dev/sdc skip=9704 ibs=8225280` didn't work.

Comment: FFS! Read `man dd` you can tell `dd` to do exactly that.

Comment: @guiverc I was fairly convinced dd was part of Ubuntu's minimal install, and thus perfectly on topic. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @vidarlo had the OP mentioned Ubuntu I'd have no issues; but the question asks only for Linux support (*covered on SE Unix & Linux*) without any specific mention of any OS.

Comment: @guiverc I can't see anything that indicates this is not Ubuntu, so I see no reason to suspect so.

Comment: It is not clear what do you actually want to do. The `dd` command that you quoted actually copied the last 25 cylinders of the `/dev/sdc` drive to file `test.img` because you skipped the first 9704 cylinders. Is this what you wanted to do? This seems opposite to wording of your question. And what do you want to do now with that file, is completely unclear. Please clarify.